# What is the effect of MOSFET switching frequency on PMSM FOC drive?

Tags: pmsm, vector-control

• I have developed FOC drive software for PMSM motor used in an electric scooter.

• Drive works fine but there is noise on the initial start-up. In order to remove it, I tried
many different approaches like estimating angle from hall sensors more precisely, increased
current loop sampling frequency but nothing gave the drive performance what I expected.

• Then I modified the PWM switching frequency from 15KHz to 20KHz and observed less noise in the
drive, But I am unable to conclude my observation, Kindly Help!!!!

Comment: Without a comprehensive measuring setup (real data) VS. estimated data comparison it's almost impossible to answer your vague question. Also you would need to do a scope trace of the BEMF voltage while sniping the motor, to check what waveform is (sine or trapezoidal). Then you should also state what are those expectations.

Answer (score 0):

The PMSM doesn't use hall sensors, it needs an encoder or some known sensorless techniques. Later it needs a start up procedure to determine the rotor position by injecting current signals and measuring voltage.

However if you made your own FOC, you should know what is the cause of this initial sound, also it is not clear why hall sensors are present in PMSM and what function they have in your FOC.

Comment: •PMSM motor which I have is a 46 pole, 1KW motor with hall sensors to give position feedback. Previously I was driving using a trapezoidal algorithm. Then I studied research paper online about implementing vector control for pmsm using Hall sensors.